# Effective implementation of list of lists

Tags: python, list, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a list of lists where:

- The size of outer list is known (e.g. N)
- The size if each element list can be different and gets determined in runtime.

A naive implementation of this can be like the following:

```
L = [[] for x in range(N)]
```

and then updating `L[i]` as data comes in like:

```
L[i] = range(M)
```

But this would to be very memory heavy since python has to copy the whole list to a new location, if the element list doesn't fit into current location.

I believe the solution would be using linked list for outer list, but due lack of a predefined link list implementation in Python, I was wondering there is another solution?

Comment: Why on earth would you have to copy the entire list in order to set a value on one element?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with accessing `L[i]` as a list like `L[i].append` or `L[i][j] = something` without having to copy the whole list....

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist @R-Nar don't forget the size of each element (which is a list) is different and varying. Evereytime that I set `L[i]` (outer list) if the element (inter list) doesn't fit python moves the whole thing to a new location. Or at least this is my understanding of what's happening.

Comment: @MBZ Yes, every time the pre-allocated array outgrows its initial size, it must be resized. This is part of dynamic arrays. The answer, to me (I could be misunderstanding), seems to be to populate the inner lists as they come instead of pre-allocating an outer list that must be resized multiple times.

Comment: In practice, CPython will allocate more room than it requires so that it doesn't have to move/resize the list every time you `append` to it. IIRC it doubles the internal size of the list whenever it exceeds capacity, so the amortized efficiency is actually O(1). This seems like a case of looking for optimizations before encountering an actual bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't store the sublists inside the outer list; it only stores references to the sublists inside the outer list. Reassigning an inner list will never require the outer list to be copied; at the implementation level, it's little more than a single pointer assignment.

If you're familiar with C# or Java, the terminology you'd be familiar with is that *everything* is a reference type in Python. If you're familiar with C++, think of it as how resizing an inner vector in a `vector<vector<int>>` wouldn't resize the outer vector.